# Is the word "oppositor" used today, or is it archaic?

Tags: word-usage, contemporary-english

The word *oppositor* does not appear in most American English dictionaries, but it does appear in the Oxford Living Dictionary.  Please, is it obsolete, archaic, or only in British usage?

Answer (score 2):

It is an archaic uncommon literary term; as you can see from [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=oppositor%20&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Coppositor%3B%2Cc0) oppositor has never been  common usage. ***Opponent*** is the more commonly used term. It appears that John Florio (of Italian origin) used the term first.

***[Oppositor](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/oppositor):***

> - Late 16th century; ***earliest use found in John Florio (1553–1625), author and teacher of languages***. From classical Latin opposit-, past participial stem of oppōnere to set against + -or, ***probably after post-classical Latin oppositor, Italian oppositore, or Middle French, French † oppositeur.***

(ODO)